# Como exportar un array a un XLSX con ionic angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Necesito realizar la exportacion desde un ion button de un xlsx teniendo un arreglo de tipo .

tengo la version de ionic 7.1.1
y la version de angular 12.1.17

No encuentro forma de exportar el archivo sin necesidad de pintar una table con HTML.

Tambien uso la libreria devexpress version 9.2 pero solo tiene la implementacion desde un grid .

alguien sabe de alguna implementaciopn para poder exportar un xlsx solo con un ion  button ?

Comment: Pinta la tabla dentro de un div de dimensión 0x0.